# Host Node API Online

Tags: node.js, api, hosting

Trying to learn more about `node` and hosting live. I have created a simple node app (`index.js`) which returns data in `json` format like dates etc. when called such as `/getDate`.
It works perfectly on localhost.
Does anyone have any easy tutorials etc on how to host this online so that I can call it from anywhere?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check the channel "Traversy Media" on youtube. He has several tutorials about how to host static and dynamic apps on platforms such as Netlify and Heroku for instance